# How can I reposition the content of a single cell in a WPF UniformGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I am creating a keypad using a `UniformGrid`. The keypad has the usual 0-9 buttons, plus a 'Backspace' button. I want the 'Backspace' button to be smaller than the numeric buttons, and so I have applied a `RenderTransform` to it. All this works fine.

However, I additionally would like the 'Backspace' button to be repositioned (realigned) `Right` and `Bottom` within the `UniformGrid` cell, so that it is away from the numeric buttons.

Below is an image with the red arrow indicating where I would like to move the 'Backspace' button.

I have tried placing the 'Backspace' button inside a ContentControl and setting the HorizontalContentAlignment and `VeriticalContentAlignment` to `Right` and `Down` respectively, but this doesn't work.

Here is some sample XAML:

```
   <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="4">
    <Button Content="1" />
    <Button Content="2" />
    <Button Content="3" />
    <Button Content="4" />
    <Button Content="5" />
    <Button Content="6" />
    <Button Content="7" />
    <Button Content="8" />
    <Button Content="9" />
    <Button />
    <Button Content="0" />
    <!--<ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment ="Bottom">-->
        <Button Content="X">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".75" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
    <!--</ContentControl>-->
</UniformGrid>
```

Can this can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RenderTransformOrigin`

```
<Button Content="X" RenderTransformOrigin="1, 1">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".75" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

It should work, however I can't test right now.